# Doubts with Designing an Azure web app file manager

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am designing a web application and it needs to be in the Azure web app. The app is focused on managing files, so it needs to upload files and store them.

As is a cloud app, I suppose that I am not able to create a directory in the web app service. My question is if I have to use the benefits of Azure and create a Storage Account and if this is the solution, What will be the best storage solution, Blob or File?

Thank you in advance.

Best wishes

Comment: Have you tried any of the option before.

Comment: Azure File Share has Directory Structure.We can create `Directories` and `Subdirectories`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Container` is a Blob Storage, which is a great option for programmable storage, where our program can read and write to the storage account.
- If we don't want to allow websites and the public to access the files, we can choose the below options.
  [image]
- Blob Storage Containers can contain any binary files/ binary large objects, there is no ordering and hierarchy, we can have a virtual folder structure.
- Containers are usually programmed to share files to access using `Shared Access Signature` and `Access Policy`

[image]

> I suppose that I am not able to create a directory in the web app service

- Azure Files is more useful for mounting a file share to a server and multiple servers can mount the same file share. It can have a quota.
- File share has a `Directory` Structure, we can create `Directories` and `Subdirectories` in a Hierarchical manner compared to `Containers`.
  [image]
- The `Connect` option in the File Share gives you details on how to mount drive onto a Windows/Linux machine.
  [image]

Use `file storage` if you need the `shared drive protocol`, if not we can design the applications and use blob storage.

As per your requirement, if you want to create `Directories` you can choose `AzureFile Share`.

Reference link [Azure Blob and Fileshare storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/450306/azure-blob-vs-fileshare-storage.html) mentioned by @deherman-MSFT